# InfoPath 2010 forms do not open in the Browser using IE8

Tags: infopath

If the user has InfoPath installed on their PC the form will default to open in InfoPath. This is not desirable. All forms should open in the browser not in InfoPath. Why? Because some users in the company my have infopath installed and some may not. It's unrealistic to uninstall InfoPath on users computers just so the forms will open in the browser.

Please review this video for more details: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkIeE8MTnSc

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint will only open the item in the browser if you browse to it from within the container (*e.g.* the Forms library itself). You can modify the XSLT on your search results to append **DefaultItemOpen=1** to the querystring (*e.g.* http://intranet/Forms/Item1.xml**?DefaultItemOpen=1**).

See [How to: Use Query Parameters to Invoke Browser-Enabled InfoPath Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772417.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: damn, beat me by seconds :)